# Cross-database query with database name in variable and cursor

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a problem with name of database in a cursor.
Here the current code

```
DECLARE @IDES INT
DECLARE @IDPROD INT

DECLARE @count INT
SET @count = 0

DECLARE CUR_CONSO CURSOR LOCAL fast_forward FOR

    SELECT E2.id_es ,P3.id_prod FROM
    [gpto_v004p001].[dbo].[GPTO_PRODETAB] P1
    INNER JOIN
    [fer_v008].[dbo].[T_PRODUIT] P3
    ON P3.GPTO_PRODUIT_ID = P1.GPTO_PRODUIT_ID
    INNER JOIN [gpto_v004p001].[dbo].[GPTO_ETAB] E1
    ON E1.ETABID = P1.ETABID
    INNER JOIN
    [fer_v008].[dbo].[t_etablissement] E2
    ON E1.ETABUC = LEFT(E2.code_es,5)
    LEFT JOIN
    [fer_v008].[dbo].[t_produit_etablissement] PE1
    ON PE1.id_prod = P3.id_prod AND PE1.id_es = E2.id_es
    WHERE PE1.id_es IS NULL AND GPTO_PRODUIT_ETAPE = 4

OPEN CUR_CONSO

FETCH CUR_CONSO INTO @IDES , @IDPROD

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS (Select * from [fer_v008].[dbo].[t_produit_etablissement] where id_es=@IDES and id_prod=@IDPROD) -- Pas d'enregistrements
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO [fer_v008].[dbo].[t_produit_etablissement]
               ([id_es],[id_prod],[gest_prod])
         VALUES
               (@IDES,@IDPROD,0)

        SET @count = @count + 1

    END

FETCH CUR_CONSO INTO @IDES , @IDPROD

END

CLOSE CUR_CONSO

DEALLOCATE CUR_CONSO
```

As the database is versionned, I need to use database name as variable saved in parameter table. 
For easy script, I use Execute command as this

```
DECLARE @base_travail varchar(128)
SELECT @base_travail = val_str_par FROM t_parametre WHERE nom_par = 'base_travail'
DECLARE @execcmd varchar(max)
SET @execcmd = 'insert into #tmpfiltres SELECT TOP 1 filtre_exu FROM ' 
  +  @base_travail + '.dbo.t_export_util WHERE id_exu =' + convert(varchar,@id_exu)
Execute (@execcmd)
```

But how do this when I have a cursor ? The 1st sample code is just a sample, whole script go over 400 lines, so I can't switch all the script in string mode.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show how you want the cursor to actually work? What are you doing inside the cursor? You've shown two code samples here and I can't piece together how they're related at all.

Comment: Also, [please don't specify varchar without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: I have add the 1st cursor. Script has 4 similar cursor.

Comment: Still don't understand. Which part of the cursor query varies? `[fer_v008]`? `[gpto_v004p001]`? Both? Do all of the variable databases have exactly the same structure?

Comment: Yes, both of the database do be dynamic. The structure is ever [base].[dbo].[table].

Comment: So where do `[gpto_v004p001]` and `[fer_v008]` come from? Do you see how hard it is to help solve your issue when we have to pull teeth to get all the little (but important) details?

Comment: The [base] name is given by DB-Admin each time we deploy new version on each application, and this script are coming from a student who are worked with us. IMO, I use SSIS to made cross base, not this, but currently this script is deployed in production and I do keep and upgrade this solution. We have already database name (fer and gpto) saved in parameter table, so my first ideas was to add variable instead hardcoded name as 2nd sample, this is the goal of my asking. I hope to have more clearly :) (and sorry for my bad english, it's not my native language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue.  Had to do with Database Compatibility Level.

This Code:

```
DECLARE @VARSql varchar(2000), @ID int;
SET @VARSql = 'USE [SomeOtherDatabase]; DECLARE cur CURSOR GLOBAL for 
  SELECT Max(SomeTableID) FROM [dbo].[SomeTable];';
Exec(@VARSql); open cur; fetch next from cur into @ID; close cur; deallocate cur;
PRINT @ID
```

Generated this error:

```
Msg 16958, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
Could not complete cursor operation because the set options have changed since the cursor was declared.
```

Running on SQL 2008 server.
Calling database has Compatibility Level 90 (Sql Svr 2005).
SomeOtherDatabase in code above has Compatibility Level 100 (Sql Svr 2008).

If you alter compatibility level so calling and called databases are the same, problem resolved.

```
select * from sys.databases
ALTER DATABASE [CallingDatabase] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100;
```

Comment: Since the time, I made a SSIS to crossbase correctly :) But thanks anyway for this tip.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. Here is my solution;

```
DECLARE CUR_CORSO CURSOR **FAST_FORWARD FORWARD_ONLY** FOR
```

...